# Android fragment replace puts fragment on top, doesn't remove old one

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have seen similar issues and tried a few things but none of that worked. I have a `MainActivity` with a layout containing a Navigation Drawer fragment and a `FrameLayout`, which I use to replace my fragments. When I click an item on the Navigation Drawer fragment, I want to replace the first fragment in `FrameLayout`. The problem is after the replace operation, my fragment appears on top of the old one, the old one isn't removed.

Here is the code for adding the first fragment when `MainActivity` launches:

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            OptionsFragment mFragment = new OptionsFragment();

            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new OptionsFragment(), OPTIONS_TAG).commit();
```

Here is the replace operation taking place in the `NavigationDrawerFragment` file:

```
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

            Fragment fragment;

            fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainActivity.OPTIONS_TAG);
            if(fragment != null)
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainActivity.LOGIN_TAG);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new LoginFragment();
                    }
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, MainActivity.LOGIN_TAG).commit();
                    closeDrawer();
                    break;
        }
    }
```

And here is the XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.kristmiha.myportal2.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I would guess that you're mixing regular `Fragment` classes and support `Fragment` classes, so the `FragmentManager` you get in `NavigationDrawerFragment` is not the support `FragmentManager`, and therefore doesn't remove the `OptionsFragment`, since it's not managing it. Which `Fragment` class do you have imported in `NavigationDrawerFragment`?

Comment: @MikeM. that's true. I'm extending `Fragment` not `FragmentActivity` in my `NavigationDrawerFragment` class. Is there a way to access the support `Fragment` from the `MainActivity`? I am using a piece of code I found on the internet for the Navigation Drawer and extending to `FragmentActivity` gives me other errors.

Comment: No, you do want it to extend `Fragment`, just make sure it's `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, not `android.app.Fragment`. Check your `import` statements.

Comment: @MikeM. Checked that, however it still cannot resolve `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Inside the `Fragment`, it'll just be `getFragmentManager()`. Only in the Activity do you use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. You just need to make sure you're extending the correct `Fragment` class.

Comment: For some reason, now I'm getting another error: Cannot cast `android.app.Fragment` to `mypackage.NavigationDrawerFragment`.
The line of code is this `mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)         getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);`

Comment: Oh just edited to `getSupportFragmentManager`. Everything is working great now. Thanks so much @MikeM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment.replace doesn't remove one fragment, works with multiple others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457844/fragment-replace-doesnt-remove-one-fragment-works-with-multiple-others)

Comment: I have the same issue but I'm sure that I'm using the support fragments.